# cambiar la URL de la barra del navegador mediante una consulta

Tags: php, javascript, .htaccess

Sé como funciona una redirección 301 mediante htaccess, ahora quiero saber si sería posible hacer lo mismo pero además cambiar la URL del navegador después de realizar una consulta a la base de datos.

Les cuento más detalles: estoy recibiendo en un archivo **.php** mediante **$_GET**  `$id=$_GET["id"];`  un id que si el cliente escribe en la barra de el navegador un número después de `mipagina.com/`, hago una consulta a la base de datos con dicho número.

Pueden ver una idea en el siguiente código:

```
 if($_GET["id"] > 0){   

 $id=$_GET["id"];

 $query=$con->query("SELECT *
         FROM nacionales
         WHERE id='$id'
         ORDER BY id DESC");
```

Si ese id coincide con el id de la base de datos, necesito que me agregue en la barra del navegador el título correspondiente a ese **id** después del id. El resultado sería algo como `mipagina.com/69/ventas-de-hilo`

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar el redireccionamiento desde php mediante `Header`

Quedaría algo como esto:

```
<?php
// Consulta tu bd.
if(!empty($id)){ //Valida si existe
 header('Location: http://mipagina.com/69/ventas-de-hilo');
 exit;
}
?>
```

Nota: No es óptimo realizar consultas a la BD sólo para verificar si existe el registro.